# Which version(32b or 64b) is good for my system configuration ?

Tags: downloads

Do I download the 32 bit or 64 bit version?

It has Intel Core2 CPU 6600@2.40 GHz & 2.00 GB RAM. 
It is running XP 32 bit.

So will 64 bit version of Ubuntu run on this machine?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can install both, because 32-bit OS is compatible with your 64-bit CPU, but to get performance benefits you should install 64-bit OS. For example [Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute/?version=14.04&architecture=amd64)

Your CPU is 64-bit:

[image]

Comment: click here, http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-decide-if-you-should-use-32bit-or-64bit-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Yep i'm running 64bit 14.04 ubuntu on Q6600 also http://ark.intel.com/products/29765/Intel-Core2-Quad-Processor-Q6600-8M-Cache-2_40-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB says **Instruction Set     64-bit**

`$ sudo lshw -c cpu
  *-cpu

       description: CPU
       product: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU    Q6600  @ 2.40GHz
       vendor: Intel Corp.
       physical id: 4
       bus info: cpu@0
       version: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU Q6600 @ 2.40GHz
       serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       slot: LGA775
       size: 1596MHz
       capacity: 3800MHz
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 266MHz
       capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority cpufreq`

`$ uname -a
Linux Vini 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, any Intel Core CPU released after 2006 (when Intel Core 2 released) is 64-bit. That includes the entire Core i series. There's no reason to install 32-bit Ubuntu unless you **know** you need an application which has problems in 64-bit environment. If you don't know of any, you're probably fine. Go ahead and install 64-bit. In fact, if you're dual booting with Windows 8 on UEFI, only the 64-bit version supports UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

With that 2 GB of ram, install a Xubuntu or Lubuntu. This will give you extra RAM, It is recomendable to update ram to run many other applications. Just like an advice.